# Trying to run program that requires X11 server on headless Raspbian install

Tags: x11, headless, xvfb

I'm trying to run a program in mono that requires a graphical server.  The Raspberry Pi it will run on is headless.  When I log in with X forwarding enabled from my local computer, I can run the program and everything is working with no input required.  I want to leave this running without being logged in, but if I detach from the session via screen, the window stays open on my local computer and continues running.  As soon as I close the window the program stops completely.

How can I "trick" the program into using a dummy virtual server?  I want to use xvfb but I'm not sure how to set it up and the guides I've found have been lacking.

Answer (score 1):

Most VNC servers will set up a "virtual" X server that you can connect to using a VNC client.  I've done some quick-and-dirty testing, and if you're using Raspbian, "tightvncserver" will do what you want.

```
$ sudo apt-get install tightvncserver
$ Xvnc :1 &
$ DISPLAY="0.0:1" navit
```

Then connect to the VNC server on port 5901 using the viewer of your choice.

Comment: I got this working with xpra (described as screen for X) but this solution looks better since I never could adjust settings on the program with X porting.  This might work better.  Thanks for the tip.